# Do the new game+ rewards carry over each time?

Tags: devil-survivor-2

At the end of the game, you are given the option to purchase a bunch of carry over options for a price.  The amount you can purchase depends on your actions through the game.  If I beat the game again, do I get to carry over the options that I've unlocked previously or do I have to purchase them every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Everything you unlock stays unlocked through every subsequent new game+ from the same original save file, including demons, compendium, titles and new game+ points.** [This thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/625210-/62280720) is essentially the same question and is given this answer, but this same answer is also found elsewhere. When you complete your game for the first time or in new game+'s, you will always be presented with the ability to purchase bonuses and I do not believe you will need to re-purchase bonuses that you've already purchased, but even if you did, as your titles and NG+ points carry over with your save, you will easily be able to afford the same options and more in subsequent new game+'s.

Comment: good to know....