# Devil Survivor 2: How to have more than 1 unique demons?

Tags: devil-survivor-2

How to have more than 1 unique demons in Devil Survivor 2? After starting new game+ do I still have all the demon fusion or only the ones that I unlocked. Can all the fusions be completed without the required demons that I got in the first game through.

Comment: Asking for Action Replay codes that do specific things are not something we can really help with; it doesn't play to our expertise whatsoever.  I'd recommend rewording your question to focus on the problem (Can I have more than one unique demon?), and let answers take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have more than 1 of each unique demon in your party at a time, that's the whole purpose.

As for new game+, you can find that information in [this other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/do-the-new-game-rewards-carry-over-each-time).

And no, you need multiple playthroughs to unlock everything as there are mutually exclusive branches in the story where unique demons and abilities show up for unlocks.

Comment: I knew that. That's why I asked for ar codes earlier. But isn't there any way to have two unique demons.